# python django why the form is not showing in the html page?

Tags: python, html, django, forms, templates

** for some reason my form is not showing in the template can someone tell me why ,
think you.
**

> views.py
> i think the problem is here but i cant find it i followed the documentation and got nothing also

````
def contact(request):
        print(request.POST)
        forms=contactform(request.POST or None)
        if forms.is_valid():
            print(forms.cleaned_data())
        context= {
          "title":"contact",
          "form": forms
            }    
            return render(request,"form.html",context)
    
     ```
      

> forms.py


         ```
    
  

  from django import forms
        
    
    class contactform(forms.ModelForm):
            full_name=forms.CharField()
            email=forms.EmailField()
            text=forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea)
        
    ```
        

>  form.html

        
          ```

    {% extends "gta.html" %}
            {% block ferr%} 
             {% if title %}
               <h1>{{title}}</h1>
             {% endif %}
             
              <form method="POST" action="."> {% csrf_token %}
                 {{forms.as_p}}
                <button type="submit">submitt</button>
              </form>  
              
            {% endblock %}
````

Comment: you passed it to the context as `form`, not `forms`, hence it is `{{ form.as_p }}`.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the StackOverflow community. Please read this helpful post to ask better questions. Please share the errors you get. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should sort you.

```
{% extends "gta.html" %}
        {% block ferr%} 
         {% if title %}
           <h1>{{title}}</h1>
         {% endif %}
         
          <form method="POST" action="."> {% csrf_token %}
             {{form.as_p}}
            <button type="submit">submitt</button>
          </form>  
          
        {% endblock %}
```